# Jsp issue in spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am building a spring application.

```
package com.capd.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public  String  home(){
    return "text";
    }
}
```

In webapp i have text.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Title</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

While i am running this app JSP is show as it is(see attached screen) Please guide me on this that how to fix this.

[image]

Web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
             id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

            <context-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring-context.xml</param-value>
            </context-param>
            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                    <param-value></param-value>
                </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>
            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
            <listener>
                <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
            </listener>

    </web-app>
```

spring-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.capd"/>
</beans>
```

and Appconfig File.

```
package com.capd.util;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

/**
 * Created by Ashish on 5/11/2016.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying your application name `localhost:8080/your_app/`

Comment: Could you share your web.xml file? probably you dont have a mapping for jsp files

Comment: Could you add your pom.xml (if you use maven)? You might be lacking some dependencies. From the top of my head it might be this one - <dependency>
 <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
 <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
 <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @cralfaro I just added all config file [DriveLink of app](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1yjb7-M3ZSWZHZLQjFrRE8yWVU)

Comment: @Abubakkar Yes I tried but no results

Comment: post your code on github and share the link here

Comment: @LynAs it is on google_drvie https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1yjb7-M3ZSWZHZLQjFrRE8yWVU Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

xml configuration is weird try to use java base config.

Watch the following video for example

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BY9YxdMg8I

AND problem with your app was web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I know its bad but you need to follow this exact syntax and context